# Using dplyr::filter with multiple conditions in conjunction with the pipe operator in R

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

How can I use a filter with multiple conditions in conjunction with the pipe %>% operator in R? For Eg:

```
x <- rep(c(2011:2012),4)
y <- sort(rep(c(1:4),2))
qtr <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
names(qtr) <- c("year","qtr")
```

Now, I need to filter records for the 3rd quarter of 2012 and I need to use the use the pipe operator in the below step.

```
z <- dplyr::filter(qtr,qtr$year==2012 & qtr$qtr==3)
```

Answer (score 4):

with your example

```
x <- rep(c(2011:2012),4)
y <- sort(rep(c(1:4),2))
qtr <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
names(qtr) <- c("year","qtr")
```

you can do:

```
dplyr::filter(qtr,year==2012 & qtr==3)
#>   year qtr
#> 1 2012   3
dplyr::filter(qtr, year==2012, qtr==3)
#>   year qtr
#> 1 2012   3
```

piping:

```
qtr %>% 
  filter(year == 2012, qtr == 3)
#>   year qtr
#> 1 2012   3
```

or step-wise

```
qtr %>% 
  filter(year == 2012) %>% 
  filter(qtr == 3)
#>   year qtr
#> 1 2012   3
```